# How to use "selectAction" Attribute of AdaptiveColumnSet() in AdaptiveCard? C#

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

```
private Attachment CardExample()
{
    AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard("1.0");
    card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveContainer()
    {
        Style = AdaptiveContainerStyle.Emphasis,

        Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
        {
            new AdaptiveColumnSet() 
            {
                Type = "ColumnSet",
                Height = AdaptiveHeight.Auto,
                SelectAction = new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
                {
                    Type="Action.Submit",
                    Id = "Submit",
                    Title="Submit",
                }
            },
        }
    });
    Attachment TestCard = new Attachment
    {
        ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
        Content= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(card)),
    };
    return TestCard; 
}
```

//It doesn't have any compiling error but when the adaptive card is rendered the Submit button don't come up
//only an empty container

Comment: Hi i am not sure about the usage of SelectAction attribute. I saw one code where someone used it in such a manner but i am not getting the result

Comment: Can you provide the JSON output here? And have you tried pasting it into the adaptive card designer and confirming the expected result? https://adaptivecards.io/designer

Comment: @MattHidinger- Thanks for replying Matt. I am trying to design the card in C# and its quite difficult to find syntax in it. Is there something missing in the above code for selecting action in columnset as its it is not Showing any syntactical error but yes not giving result either.

Answer (score 1):

ColumnSets are able to contain an on click action but there is no button dispayed, it's really as simple as that.  If I click on the `ColumnSet`, it performs the action.

I've included some images, etc. below that illustrate it working.  It's a bit clunky but you can see what I mean.

The example is an `OpenUrl` and it opens up to google.com, a `Submit` action works the same, just include the data you want to send back to the bot and the catch it and deal with it in `OnTurnAsync` (if you're using v4 framework) ...

[image]

[image]

I know this answer is lacking but ... it is the answer.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your implementation is that you are adding a **selectAction** on an empty container. A column set needs columns and each column needs content. In your case, there are no actual items in the columns and hence there will be nothing to click on.

Here is an example of how the column set should be implemented :

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [

    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "spacing": "medium",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": "auto",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "Image",
              "url": "https://unsplash.it/80?image=1083",
              "size": "medium"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": 4,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Silver Star Mountain"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Maps",
              "isSubtle": true,
              "spacing": "none"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "selectAction": {
        "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
        "title": "Silver Star Mountain",
        "url": "ms-cortana:silver-star-mountain"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```